# xarray - Merge multiple DataArray objects with overlapping or missing time coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-xarray

I have multiple netCDF files and they are loaded into DataArray objects using xarray with three dimensions [`time`, `latitude`, `longitude`].

The `latitude` and `longitude` coordinates are identical while some have overlapping or missing coordinates in the `time` dimension.

```
**da1**：

time    (time)    datetime64[ns]    2017-10-03T18:00:00 ... 2017-10-...

array(['2017-10-03T18:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-03T19:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-03T20:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-03T21:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-03T22:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-03T23:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T00:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T02:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T04:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T05:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T06:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T07:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T08:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T09:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T10:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T11:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T12:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T13:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T14:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T15:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T16:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T17:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T18:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T19:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')

**d2**:
time
(time)
datetime64[ns]
2017-10-04T13:00:00 ... 2017-10-...

array(['2017-10-04T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T14:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T15:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T16:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T17:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T18:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T19:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T20:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T21:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-04T22:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-04T23:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T00:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-05T01:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T02:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-05T03:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T04:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-05T05:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-05T07:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-05T09:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T10:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-05T11:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T12:00:00.000000000',
       '2017-10-05T13:00:00.000000000', '2017-10-05T14:00:00.000000000'],
      dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

I would like to run "concat" or "merge" or "combine" them by the `time` coordinates. The time coordinates would run from '2017-10-03T18:00:00.000000000' to '2017-10-05T14:00:00.000000000'. Use the newer values where overlapping coordinates occur. For example, use the value from the `da2` where time = '2017-10-04T13:00:00.000000000'. Use `nan` if the `time` coordinates are missing from the input DataArray objects.

I tried:

```
da_merged = xr.merge([da2, da1], compat="override")
```

But I ended up with a whole bunch of `nan` values for the time coordi?nates in `da1`. Can I have some directions which method/params I should use

Answer (score 0):

I hope you solved it, but for me it worked simply doing:

```
da_merged=xr.Dataset()
file_paths_list =[da1,da2]

for file in file_paths_list:

        da_merged = xr.merge([da_merged,xr.open_mfdataset(file)],compat='override')
```